# Show/Hide Icon in Entry does not shown

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I am trying to create a show/hide password for my entry.

after adding this code on the Android Project. The show and hide effects are working. but the Icon of show and hide effects are not visible inside the entry.

```
using Android.Graphics.Drawables;
using Android.Text.Method;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

[assembly: ResolutionGroupName("Xamarin")]
[assembly: ExportEffect(typeof(ShowHidePassEx.Droid.Effects.ShowHidePassEffect), "ShowHidePassEffect")]
namespace ShowHidePassEx.Droid.Effects
{
    public class ShowHidePassEffect : PlatformEffect
    {


        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            ConfigureControl();
        }

        protected override void OnDetached()
        {
        }

        private void ConfigureControl()
        {
            EditText editText = ((EditText)Control);
            editText.SetCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(0,0, Resource.Drawable.avd_show_password,0);
            editText.SetOnTouchListener(new OnDrawableTouchListener());

        }
    }

    public class OnDrawableTouchListener : Java.Lang.Object, Android.Views.View.IOnTouchListener
    {
        public bool OnTouch(Android.Views.View v, MotionEvent e)
        {
            if (v is EditText && e.Action == MotionEventActions.Up)
            {
                EditText editText = (EditText)v;
                if (e.RawX >= (editText.Right - editText.GetCompoundDrawables()[2].Bounds.Width()))
                {
                    if (editText.TransformationMethod == null)
                    {
                        editText.TransformationMethod = PasswordTransformationMethod.Instance;
                        editText.SetCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, Resource.Drawable.avd_show_password, 0);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        editText.TransformationMethod = null;
                        editText.SetCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, Resource.Drawable.avd_hide_password, 0);
                    }

                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Am I doing it right? what could be the possible cause of not showing the icon inside the entry, and what is the solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I guess I found out the Answer.

the problem is this,

```
  editText.SetCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, Resource.Drawable.avd_hide_password, 0);
```

I change that to this.

```
  editText.SetCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, GetDrawable(proyekto4juan.Droid.Resource.Mipmap.HidePass), null);
```

And for the `GetDrawable` function.

```
public static BitmapDrawable GetDrawable(int resID)
{
    var context = global::Android.App.Application.Context;
    var drawable = ContextCompat.GetDrawable(context, resID);
    var bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).Bitmap;
    return new BitmapDrawable(Resources.System, Bitmap.CreateScaledBitmap(bitmap, 60, 60, true));
}
```

The `GetDrawable` Function is for resizing the Icon inside the Entry.

Comment: accept your answer so that others may try to use it